# How to show "Success" or "Failure" in roll20 macros?

Tags: roll20

I'm setting up Roll20 macros to play Frostmark, a DnD 5e derivative that has a mana mechanic of sorts; Spells are powered by souls and if you fail a soul check when casting a spell, you lose the soul you were using to power the spell.

I'm trying to set up a macro for that, which is here (DC is 12+ spell level, relevant modifier is +6).

```
&{template:default}{{name=Soul check}}{{ [[ 1d20 + 6 > [[?{Spell level} + 12]] ]] }}
```

Right now, it's just showing the roll result and mousing over is showing e.g. `1d20+6>17 = (14)+6`

I want it to say "Success" or "Failure" in the macro result, or at least the "0 successes" or "1 success" you get when using roll commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was writing this question, I managed to figure it out. The syntax requires that the roll be enclosed in `{}`, so the correct formula is

```
&{template:default}{{name=Soul check}}{{ [[ {1d20+6}>[[?{Spell level} + 12]] ]] Success }}
```

As far as I can tell, there is no if/else in the macros, so closest to a solution to get it to say "Success" or "Failure" that I can find would be to use Mike deBoston's [conditional text](https://app.roll20.net/forum/post/5899495/roll20-tips-and-tricks-innovative-solutions-to-common-problems/?pageforid=8788506#post-8788506) method to choose the text; Set up two tables, `sf0` with the item "Failure" and `sf1` with the item "Success" and request a roll from a table.

I only ever got to

```
&{template:default}{{name=Soul check}}{{ [[1t[sf[[ {1d20+6}>[[?{Spell level}+ 12]] ]] ]] }}
```

Which is outputting`[[ 1t[sf0`. I have [asked about this separately](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/192776/can-a-roll20-macro-select-a-rollable-table-according-to-a-rollish-result), but I suspect this is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

See the full application of this in [my answer to the related question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/194901/28326)

---

1. Make a Rollable Table "0" and a Rollable Table "1"
2. Enter one or more phrases indicating Success in Table "1" and Failure in Table "2"
3. Make a macro using the syntax [[1t[ [[(roll)>(target)]] ] ]]

- The roll is use to parse "1t[ ... ]" into a Rollable Table Call, and the > operator provides a 1 (successful) or 0 (failure) output, meaning the appropriate Rollable Table will be called and presented instead of the normal roll output.

---

Your other answer isn't actually correct; {} brackets allows your +6 to be added before comparing to the rest of the roll, but putting ?{{Spell level} + 12 in it's own [[]] roller doesn't allow it to be compared to your 1d20+6> . The best solution I cold come up with is a drop-down variable to replace manually entering spell levels; this allows you to add the 12 directly in so the > is comparing to exactly one number instead of 12 (then adding spell level).

```
&{template:default} {{name=Soul Check}} {{ [[ {1d20+6}>?{Level?|1,13|2,14|3,15|4,16|5,17|6,18|7,19|8,20|9,21} ]] }}
```

I'm assuming spells don't go above level 9, as is the case with default D&D 5e. Of course you can edit the number of entries, following the progression, to expand on that.

The output of the above macro is either 1 for success or 0 for failure.

Comment: I experimented by changing the macro to `{{ [[ {1d1+6}>[[?{Spell level} + 1]] ]] Success }}` and it seems to work as expected (i.e. spell level 6 succeeds as the comparison is equal-or-greater, but spell level 7 fails).

Comment: @Haem That's strange bc when I tested the whole statement from your answer, I didn't get results as expected.