# Can a Roll20 macro select a rollable table according to a roll(ish) result?

Tags: roll20

In coming up with an answer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/192770/how-to-show-success-or-failure-in-roll20-macros), I found a [method to reference a table according to a variable](https://app.roll20.net/forum/post/5899495/roll20-tips-and-tricks-innovative-solutions-to-common-problems/?pageforid=8788506#post-8788506). Quite different to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163433/how-can-i-make-a-roll20-macro-that-shows-different-text-depending-on-the-result), the solution concatenates a variable to a table name prefix to fetch a value from a single-item rollable table.

I tried to generalize this to use a success count as the suffix, and ended up with the code below, with two tables called `sf0` and `sf1` with the single rows "Failure" and "Success", respectively.

```
&{template:default}{{name=Soul check}}{{ [[1t[sf[[ {1d20+6}>[[?{Spell level}+ 12]] ]] ]] }}
```

Which doesn't evaluate the `1t` function, and instead outputs `[[1t[sf0` or `[[1t[sf1`. Is it possible to concatenate a roll result into a prefix to roll on a selected table?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem seems to be that

- **[[1t[sf[[** {1d20+6}>[[?{Spell level}+ 12]] ]] ]]

is not the correct syntax to [call a roll table](https://wiki.roll20.net/Roll_Table#Using). It should have one less bracket around the roll itself and should not include "sf" like so:

- [[1t[ [[{1d20+6}>[[?{Spell level}+ 12]] ] ]]

The linked [forums'](https://app.roll20.net/forum/post/5899495/stupid-roll20-tricks-and-some-clever-ones/?pageforid=7510651#post-7510651) suggestion is to simply have the tables be "0" and "1" so that, whichever result is achieved by the die roll (0 or 1), gets passed as the **Rollable Table name to be called**. This *should* result in your success/failure messages being posted instead of 1/0.

**Unfortunately,** your method of setting the variable DC confuses the macro into thinking there are ]] close brackets; it may work better using HTML coding, but I would have to look that up before attempting that solution.

### Fortunately

... the text from my other answer can be adopted to do this correctly, for sure, and the information here may allow you to fix your method if you prefer:

```
&{template:default} {{name=test macro}} {{ [[ 1t[[[ {1d20}>?{Level?|1,13|2,14|3,15|4,16|5,17|6,18|7,19|8,20|9,21} ]]] ]] }}
```

You should additionally have a table, named simply "1" and another named simply "0" (no letters) [image: Roll Tables]

Within each should be one (or more) text values indicating Success or Failure. [image: Roll Table Items]

---

**Note:** I ran into an issue that the "1t [[[" wasn't calling the Roll Tables; this was caused by the space. Your text doesn't have it, but note that it must be "1t[[[" in order for the answer to be parsed.

Post-Note: If your intent with including "sf" in the Rollable Tables was to allow for multiple different macros with different success/failure output, then you should be able to make further table pairs (2/3, 4/5, 6/7 etc) and add 2/4/6(...) to the result after your 1d20> but within the 1t[ ] call.